# Remember Me failing scripted event

Tags: pc, remember-me

Has anyone encountered this bug before and fixed it? During Edge's Shortcut, there is a part where you jump across a ledge but the pipe breaks and you [fall onto the fan unit thing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=t8mc8vXy7Ls#t=801s). Instead, I get this:

[image: bug]

Its preventing me from continuing the game.

Anyone know how to fix it? I have verified the files through Steam.

EDIT: I have even uninstalled the game and reinstalled it, but the problem is still there

Comment: Do you get this always? If not try reloading the checkpoint. That helped me in a similar situation.

Comment: @RalZarek Yes this always happens, whether i leave the game, reload or die

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this answer which seems to work: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130605094953AAWQvhx

> Try turning off super sampling and playing on the lowest resolution

I only changed the resolution since supersampling was already off for me